# Filtered copy array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I made reducer ad my goal i filtered that. Look at my code:

```
    case 'ACTIVE_USER':
        return {
            ...state,
            users: state.users.filter(user => user.active === 1)
        }
    case 'UNACTIVE_USER':
        return {
            ...state,
            users: state.users.filter(user => user.active === 0)
        }
```

It works if I run some case. But if I show active users and then I'll try show unactive users it display nothing. I think that I work on this same array not on copy and here is problem. How can I filtered all the time this same array and siplay active on unactive user when I want?

Comment: you are missing a `'` after UNACTIVE_USER

Comment: I'm having a pretty hard time understanding what you're saying. You made a reducer ad your goal that you filtered? Is there an issue with your switch case returning objects? Where are you showing active users and do you have a reproducible example of something not being shown?

Comment: You need to keep two states for that, one is `users` and other one is `filteredUsers`, so in users you will have the list of all users, and every time you filter `filteredUsers: state.users.filter(user => user.active === 1)` use the `filteredUsers` array in your components

Answer (score 1):

Maintain only 'active' state in store.

```
case 'ACTIVE_USER':
    return {
        ...state,
        active: 1
    }
case 'UNACTIVE_USER':
    return {
        ...state,
        active: 0
    }
```

In the components

```
const active = <from store>;
const users = <from store>;
const data = users.filter(user => user.active === active)
```

Comment: this is the correct approach. writing derived state to your store is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `users` unchanged and add `filteredUsers` in store.

```js
case 'ACTIVE_USER':
  return {
    ...state,
    filteredUsers: state.users.filter(user => user.active === 1)
  }
case 'UNACTIVE_USER':
  return {
    ...state,
    filteredUsers: state.users.filter(user => user.active === 0)
  }
```

Then use `filteredUsers` in component level.

Answer (score -1):

it happened because you override state.users each time you use state.users.filter

so you need to make new array of filteredUsers and make all your computations so as not to affect original users array